# How can I post feed to other user wall by javascript sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, feed

I've succeed to publish feed to my wall but not to another user wall 
I've defined both 'from' and 'to' variable

but I got error message when publishing the feed which said 
"An error occurred. Please try again later."

here is my code when publishing

```
var obj = {
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'http://apps.facebook.com/' + fb_app_id,
    picture: app_url + 'icon/test.png',
    from: facebookid1,
    to: facebookid2,
    name: 'Test App',
    caption: 'This is a test!!',
    description: 'Test to publish feed to other user wall'
};

function callback(response) {
    // Callback after feed posted...
}
FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

I don't know what is wrong or their are any extend permission required ?

Comment: I presume you're logged in as 'facebookid1' when triggering the dialog?

Comment: Yes it's true, I think it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
FB.ui(    {
  method: 'feed',
  name: name,
  link: link,//Link is any link you want to post
  picture: picture,
  caption: caption,
  description: redemption,
  message: message,
  to: page_id,
  from: page_id    
 },    
function (response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert(response.post_id);
    } else {

    }    
   }  
);
```

also if a user have set privacy that no once can post anything on their's wall, you'll unable to post in this case